# Paracol and Setspace

Tags: setspace, paracol

`paracol` seems to "grab" the white space from the paragraph preceding it. This wouldn't be noticeable if I wasn't using the `setspace` package.

How do I force `paracol` to begin the background color at the start of the new paragraph instead of starting at the end of the previous paragraph?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{2em}

\lipsum[1]

\backgroundcolor{c0}{red}
\begin{paracol}{1}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can try with `\backgroundcolor{c[0](0pt,-\parskip)(0pt,0pt)}{red}`

Comment: That works most of the time @touhami, but sometimes I get the first line cut by the red (in my main document)